# Disable editing record in table if used as reference in another

Tags: sql-server

I've a vouchers status table contains (id,description)
used as reference in several tables.

I want to stop editing record if used as reference in any other table. I am trying to get all reference and check if used is not working because I want to make the restriction on the query for crud operations.

Is there functions like

```
if object_id('object name','type') is null
```

Comment: At first glance, it's not clear what you are asking please explain bit more

Comment: I think you are looking for [Foreign Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I've data in table used as reference in another table ,
i want to make a check while editing this data , if used user can't edit , else can edit, i know that i can do it from coding , but i'm asking if there is a db check which i can rely on to make it faster

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the foreign key for the vouchers status table for any table?If not please do like this it will work.

Comment: I've implemented foreign key , you can't delete record ,it's ok , the problem is that i want to stop user from editing by using database built in function if exist